# Does a UA envoy warforged have to choose a specific vehicle?

Tags: dnd-5e, unearthed-arcana, racial-traits, vehicles, warforged

According to the [accepted answer that was written by Dinomaster](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/136735/can-a-warforged-envoy-pick-a-land-vehicle-as-his-integrated-tool/136748#136748) to [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/136735/can-a-warforged-envoy-pick-a-land-vehicle-as-his-integrated-tool), the [envoy warforged from Unearthed Arcana: Eberron Races](https://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/723UA_EberronRaces7232018.pdf#page=9) can choose a vehicle for their integrated tool. However, on the table on page 154 of the *Player’s Handbook*, “Vehicles (land or water)” is listed as one type of tool.

So, question(s):

1. Can the warforged choose the vehicle type each time they use the ability(longboat, rowboat, etc.)
2. If the answer to the previous question is yes, does the warforged have to choose land or water vehicles at character creation, or can they use both interchangeably (because “Vehicles (land or water)” is listed as one type of tool, but uses “or”, which can be inclusive or exclusive)?

Comment: I assume you're intentionally ignoring that choosing vehicles for Integrated Tool goes against design intent, as pointed out in the other answer to that question?

Comment: @V2Blast Yes I’m going by strict RAW.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## Yes, you have to choose one

You have to

> Choose **a** tool you're proficient with

That doesn’t let you choose a type of tool, you have to choose a specific singular tool from the type. “Vehicles” isn’t singular any more than “musical instruments” is singular. “A rowboat” or “a bagpipe” are singular options.

Your integrated tool is the specific one integrated at creation, not a transforming generic ability to manifest any kind of tool in a category.

If it said you could customise the specific tool on use instead of at character creation, it would say so.

Comment: Yes, but “musical instruments” is a category on the tools table, while “vehicles (land or water) is a single row.

Comment: @MrHiTech It doesn’t say to choose category of tool you are proficient with, it says to choose a singular tool you are proficient with. How the list of equipment is typeset for space and readability convenience is not relevant, and the rules do not reference the table anyway.

Comment: @Medix2 I’m not sure if that would add anything. What do you have in mind?

Comment: To add to what @Medix2 said, alchemists’ supplies (for example) are one set of tools; you are proficient with them or you’re not. Therefore, if you can be partially proficient with “vehicles (land or water)”, they are not one type of tool.

Comment: Note that your interpretation here is, while certainly consistent with the text, contrary to designer intent (see e.g. [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/139087/14848)): the part where it's a specific singular tool is supposed to just be fluff you can refluff however you want so long as the crunch-- having expertise in and the equipment to use a single tool proficiency-- is the same.  That said, "Vehicles" is not a single tool proficient so even if you are playing with that you would have to pick "land vehicles" or "water vehicles", not both.

Comment: @MrHiTech alchemist’s supplies are *a* tool. Same as you don’t have to pick an individual carriage wheel in your scenario, the whole collection is a singular tool.

Answer (score 8):

I disagree with your statement that

> on page 154 of the Player’s Handbook, “Vehicles (land or water)” is listed as one type of tool.

The entry on the table is footnoted to go look at the Mounts & Vehicles section, so it's clearly indicating that for those proficiencies, you need to go look somewhere else. It isn't saying they're one single proficiency, but rather a category, like *Gaming set* or *Musical instrument*.

You'd need to flip to the correct section, and pick one specific vehicle that fits your skill proficiency to be your integrated tool (and of course clear it with your DM, because you're doing something *rather goofy*). You can't choose a new tool every time you use the ability, any more than you could pick a new set of *Artisan's tools* each time you pull them out.

Of course, this is only based on the *Wayfinder's Guide* warforged. If you wait a couple of weeks, the official Eberron book will come out, and most likely warforged will no longer be able to have integrated vehicles at all.

Comment: I believe the footnote is talking about cost and weight. It does not indicate that vehicles (land or water) is not one single category of tool.

Comment: Crawford confirms in [an interview here](https://www.whatwouldthesmartpartydo.com/2019/10/29/jeremy-crawford-interview/) (which is [summarized here](https://www.enworld.org/threads/interview-with-jeremy-crawford-on-eberron-rising-from-the-last-war.668267/)) that warforged no longer have subraces, though they will still have some customization options.